# Extract Data from the pages that are Hyperlinked in a Page

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract amenities and furnishing data from all the pages that are hyper linked in a page and save them as list of lists . I have tried using this code but it gives an empty list . What is wrong in this code ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 
import requests
link2 = []
s=[]
s2 = []
url = "https://www.makaan.com/gurgaon-residential-property/buy-property-in-gurgaon-city?budget=2,"
r = requests.get(url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content , 'html.parser')
for a21 in Soup.findAll('a',class_="typelink"):
    c=a21.get('href')
    link2.append(c)
for url2 in link2:
    r2 = requests.get(url2)
    Soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content , 'html.parser')
    for x in Soup2.findAll('div',class_="listitem  js-moblist-item"):
        x1 = Soup2.find('div',class_="txt")
        s.append(x1.text)
    s2.append(s)
```

---

I like to get the output as list of lists that contains the information in "listitem  js-moblist-item " div .

Comment: `"listitem js-moblist-item"` doesn't exist in any of the `urls` from `link2`.  You also never call `x` in that last `for-loop`

Comment: It worked . Thanks .